# clicking function not working as per expected in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array and it contains 10 objects. I am looping over the array using ng-repeat. While looping I have two conditions. When I click on the button, I need to show some data and when I click on the button I need to hide data. But it is not working.

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">          
    <div ng-click="showData()"></div>
    <div ng-show="isShowingData">
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="isHidingingData">
        <span>{{item.id}}</span>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.isShowingData = false;
$scope.isHidingingData = true;

$scope.showMoreAttr=function() { 

    if ($scope.isShowingData == true) {
        $scope.isShowingData = false;
        $scope.isHidingingData = true;
    } else if($scope.isShowingData == false) {
        $scope.isShowingData=true;
        $scope.isHidingingData=false;
    }
};
```

Now buttons will print 10 times. When I click the show button, it will show the all objects and when I click hide, it will hide all the objects.

Could You please help how to avoid this problem and solve the single object?

Comment: Template `ng-click` is `showData()` yet the only method in your controller is `showMoreAttr()`

Comment: yes, could you please any help @gillesc

Comment: See my answer, sorted it based on your code and showing a simplified way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the state per items, not at the scope level or it will be applied to all the items. Here is how you could do it.

Update the template to pass the item and use the same variable name but as property of item for ng-show and ng-hide.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">          
    <div ng-click="showData(item)">Click</div>
    <div ng-show="item.isShowingData">
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="item.isHidingingData">
        <span>{{item.id}}</span>
    </div> 
</div>
```

then update your controller to use `item` and you can simply use `else` instead `else if`:

```
$scope.showData = function(item) { 

    if (item.isShowingData) {
        item.isShowingData = false;
        item.isHidingingData = true;
    } else {
        item.isShowingData = true;
        item.isHidingingData = false;
    }
};
```

You could even simplify further by only having a single property

Template

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">          
    <div ng-click="showData(item)">Click</div>
    <div ng-show="item.isShowingData">
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="item.isShowingData">
        <span>{{item.id}}</span>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.showData = function(item) { 
    item.isShowingData = !item.isShowingData;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

- pass your item to the function as parameter.
- use item.isShowingData and item.isHidingData
- in the html bind to item.isShowingData and item.isHidingData

the result should be single switching.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store this in your item.Else your button will affect every single item.
I also use a single boolean instead of two. You don't need a boolean for hide and an other for show. One is the opposite of the other anyway. It's simplify the controller a lot.

**Html :**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">          
    <div ng-click="showData(item)"></div>
    <div ng-show="item.isShowingData">
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="!item.isShowingData">
        <span>{{item.id}}</span>
    </div> 
</div>
```

**Controller :**

```
$scope.showData=function(item) {     
   item.isShowingData = !item.isShowingData;
};
```